# Intel syntax is [eax+ebx], what is AT&T syntax equivalent?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

The question at [strlen in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041481/strlen-in-assembly)
is about strlen in assembly, but that seems to be written in AT&T syntax, which unfortunately isn't supported by my assembler.

I'm just curious how would you  translate the syntax [eax + ebx] to the intel's syntax?

So

```
4(%eax)     # offset 4
```

is equivalent to

```
[eax + 4]
```

Suppose the offset value is stored in %ebx.
What's the equivalence of

```
[eax + ebx]
```

?

```
%ebx(%eax)     # doesn't work!
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[eax+ebx]` should be translated to `(%eax,%ebx)`.

The full syntax for memory addresses in AT&T syntax is:

```
offset(%reg1,%reg2,scale)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[reg1 + reg2*scale + offset]
```

`offset` and `scale` are constant values, and `scale` must be 1, 2, 4, or 8. Defaults are 0 for offset and 1 for scale.